# make sub menu open on hover not on click

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, onhover

Hello i have this menu that i want it to open the sub menus on hover.

[here is the test](http://jsfiddle.net/rtyynb6L/) its just missing a icon but dont mind it. Can you pin point where should i change the css. Thanks

```
  <div id="cssmenu" style="margin-top:80px">
  <ul>

  <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><img src="ico.png" width="19" height="19" style="margin-right:10px"><span>Resturant</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li ><a href="resturant.html"><span>MENU</span></a>

     </li>
     <li ><a href=''><span>SELSKABER</span></a>

     </li>
       <li><a href=''><span>KOGEBØGER MM.</span></a>

     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='gallery.html'><img src="ico.png" width="19" height="19" style="margin-right:10px"><span>Undstilling</span></a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='contact.html'><img src="ico.png" width="19" height="19" style="margin-right:10px"><span>Om stedet</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy friend try this

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').mouseover(function(){
//or
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('mouseover', function(){
```

See this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/rtyynb6L/1/)

Comment: hello this did the work but as u can see the animation is continuint a couple of times and i want it to hover on and show the items and stop.

Comment: Oh, is truth! See this http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/rtyynb6L/2/, using .mouseenter()